# SQL Query use multiple criteria and LIKE wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if one of the involved person names (1,2,3 or 4) exists in my database. I tried the following query but it doesnt work as i want.

```
SELECT *
FROM db.cases
WHERE (inv_person_name_1 OR inv_person_name_2 OR inv_person_name_3 OR inv_person_name_4) LIKE '%something%'
```

I also can't use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM db.cases
WHERE inv_person_name_1 LIKE '%something%'
      OR inv_person_name_2 LIKE '%something%'
      OR inv_person_name_3 LIKE '%something%'
      OR inv_person_name_4 LIKE '%something%'
```

because it doesn't fit my program needs. I need to have only one LIKE '%something%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using C# (as it is currently tagged), you need to format your query with SqlParameters:

```
SELECT * FROM db.cases 
WHERE inv_person_name_1 LIKE {0} 
OR inv_person_name_2 LIKE {0} 
OR inv_person_name_3 LIKE {0} 
OR inv_person_name_4 LIKE {0};
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM db.cases 
WHERE inv_person_name_1 LIKE @name 
OR inv_person_name_2 LIKE @name 
OR inv_person_name_3 LIKE @name  
OR inv_person_name_4 LIKE @name;
```

In which case you need to do `cmd.BindByName = true;` (see [better way of using a single parameter multiple times in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917881/better-way-of-using-a-single-parameter-multiple-times-in-c-sharp))

Another alternative which is ugly, but if your LIKE will always be in the `%something%` format (that is, wild card before AND after), you can concatenate the names thus:

```
SELECT * FROM db.cases 
WHERE (inv_person_name_1 || '+' || inv_person_name_2 || '+' || inv_person_name_3 || '+' || inv_person_name_4) LIKE @name;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM db.cases 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('+', inv_person_name_1, inv_person_name_2, inv_person_name_3, inv_person_name_4) LIKE @name;
```

Comment: First,Thank you for trying to help.

The last query you wrote seems to fit my needs but it doesn't work correctly. it only checks for the inv_person_name_4 if it matches the @name. other ideas to fix this?

Comment: @Michael_Panayiotou You mean the concatenation does that? Maybe try `CONCAT_WS('+',inv_person_name_1,inv_person_name_2,inv_person_name_3,inv_person_name_4)` ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws))

Comment: Just be sure you use a separator that is unique enough that it cannot be in your names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM db..cases WHERE inv_person_name IN (1, 2, 3, 4) -- for integer types

SELECT * FROM db..cases WHERE inv_person_name IN ('1', '2', '3', '4') -- for varchar types
```

Comment: AND inv_person_name_4 LIKE '%something%'

Comment: this does not seem to be a solution to my problem. I'm trying to search for an involved person that in my database might be in inv_person_1 or inv_person_2 or inv_person_3 or inv_person_4 column. I'm trying to do something similar to my first query in the description (using Like only one time)